# MATLAB swap columns of two different matrices

Tags: matlab

Im using matlab and am having some difficulty. I am trying to swap the columns of one matrix (A) with the column of another matrix (B). For Example:

A =

```
 4     6     5  
 7     8     4     
 6     5     9    
 1     0     0     
 0     1     0     
 0     0     1
```

B =

```
 1     0     0     0     0     0
 0     1     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     0     0     0
 0     0     0    -1     0     0
 0     0     0     0    -1     0
 0     0     0     0     0    -1
```

Is there a way to tell Matlab to switch, for instance, column 1 in A with column 3 in B?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually perform this column swap in one line and without the need for dummy variables using the function [DEAL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/deal.html):

```
[A(:,1),B(:,3)] = deal(B(:,3),A(:,1));
```

Comment: +1 good one, although it seems like an overkill for such a simple task

Comment: @Amro: Perhaps, but DEAL is a useful function to know about in general, so I figured I might as well list it as another possible solution. ;)

Answer (score 5):

```
tmp = A(:,1);
A(:,1) = B(:,3);
B(:,3) = tmp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
A(:,1) = B(:,3);
```

Or to actually swap them, you can use:

```
dummy = A(:,1);
A(:,1) = B(:,3);
B(:,3) = dummy;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this only takes what was in matrix B and puts it in A. Is there something that will take the column from B to A, and from A to B?